# How to add LWC component as Button?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

I need to add a button to Opportunity Line Item. It could be Screenflow, but it can only be added as an Action, and you can't create an Action on an Opportunity Line Item object, only a button and a link. So I decided to write a lwc component, but I don't know how to add it like button or link